# What is the point of @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

As far as I understand, this annotation is used to get authenticated User in Controller. But I can get a user without it just with the following code:

```
@GetMapping("/example")
public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) { 
    return authentication.getName(); 
}
```

I would appreciate if you could tell me what is the use of it or share some docs as I could not find one.
I do appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This annotation is used to resolve a `Principal` to your method argument, more specifically, a `Authentication#getPrincipal()`. For example, if you have a custom `UserDetails` implementation, like `CurrentUser implements UserDetails`, that is returned by your `UserDetailsService` you can resolve it directly into your method:

```java
@GetMapping("/example")
public String currentCustomProperty(@AuthenticationPrincipal CurrentUser currentUser) { 
    return currentUser.getCustomProperty(); 
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to do:

```java
@GetMapping("/example")
public String currentCustomProperty(Authentication authentication) {
    CurrentUser currentUser = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return currentUser.getCustomProperty(); 
}
```

Also, it helps to decouple your Spring MVC layer from Spring Security's implementations:

```java
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {}

@GetMapping("/example")
public String currentCustomProperty(@CurrentUser CurrentUser currentUser) { 
    return currentUser.getCustomProperty(); 
}
```

You can even apply `SpEL` to the annotation and customize what it will return.

There are more details in [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#mvc-authentication-principal).